# Creating dropdown navigation using only css

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` list with nested `ul` elements. Currently it goes 3 levels deep. (main navigation, child, grandchild). I can't seem to get the dropdowns to work. Unforunately, I do not have the ability to place id's in the (ul) items. The best I could do i wrap the `ul` in a `div` with an ID on it. Any idea how I could do this? Here's the code I was working with, and I'm sorry if my css looks bad or makes no sense. I'm a novice at this.

**Code**
http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/ZhNDZ/1/ (jsfiddle for CSS)

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="but_products" ><a href="/products">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="but_boilers" ><a href="/products/boilers">Boilers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="but_resources" ><a href="/resources">Resources</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="but_engineeringLibrary" ><a href="/resources/engineering_library">Engineering Library</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="but_detroit" ><a href="/resources/engineering_library/detroit_radiant_mea_numbers">Detroit Radiant MEA numbers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="but_contactUs" ><a href="/contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a functioning 3-tier CSS drop-down navigation system:

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Menu One
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu One Item One</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu One Item Two</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Two Submenu Item One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Two Submenu Item Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Two Submenu Item Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Two Submenu Item Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu One Item Three</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Three Submenu Item One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Three Submenu Item Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Three Submenu Item Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Three Submenu Item Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Menu One Item Four</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Four Submenu Item One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Four Submenu Item Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Four Submenu Item Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Four Submenu Item Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu Two
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; }
a:hover { color: #cc0000; }

/* Hide submenu */
nav ul > li > ul,
nav ul > li > ul > li > ul { display:none; }

/* Layout menubar and menus */
nav { background:#ddd; padding:0.25em 0.5em; }
nav > ul > li { cursor: pointer; display:inline-block; padding:0 1em; }
nav > ul > li > ul { background: #ddd; padding:0.5em; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; }
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul { background: #ccc; padding:0.5em; position: absolute; left: 90%; top: 0; z-index: 1001; }

/* show submenu on hover */
nav ul > li:hover > ul,
nav ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul { display:block; width:10em; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/nrAPu/

Hope this helps.